# Why do I get a "0x1004" when trying to deploy my solana anchor IDL?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

When I try to deploy an IDL with anchor, I get a cryptic "Custom Error 0x1004" message. What does this mean:?

```
$ anchor idl init --provider.cluster testnet --filepath ./target/idl/myprogram.json sa3BafcCxwD6G3tUbvTcvnCD28sCXhpasauLtpw9HdA
Error: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1004
```

Answer (score 5):

0x1004 is hexadecimal for 4100, or the [DeclaredProgramIdMismatch](https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/blob/master/lang/src/error.rs#L164) error.

So somewhere in your program, you're declaring a different program id than the one you deployed with:

```rust
declare_id!("some_other_program_id"); // this is not your program id!
```